# vba cell find empty and change value in different cell

Tags: excel, cell, vba

I need help with this problem:

If any cell in column A is empty then in Columns D and E delete cells in the same row but shift up only cells in Columns D and E, Column A will stay untouched...

Comment: Macro code for this situation in principle for cells shifting is :`Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Application.WindowState = xlNormal
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "a"
    Range("D1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("E1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub` Convert it to suitable and proper VBA code.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub DeleteUP_D_and_E_IF_A_IsEmpty()

    Dim LastRow As Long, x As Long

    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


    For x = 2 To LastRow

        If Cells(x , 1) = "" Then Range(Cells(x, "D"), Cells(x, "E")).Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you need a `Chicken` ? ;)

Comment: lol..Do you know what they have to eat at work today?  Fried Chicken.  Do you know what they had yesterday?  Baked Chicken.  I don't know what there are severing tomorrow.  Must be Mystery Chicken!!!

Comment: You have switched the row variable from `i` to `x`.  This will work if you use `i` as the row reference for the cells (e.g. `Cells(i, 1)).

Comment: If I understand the question, I think you need to delete column A and shift those cells too.  I would presume columns B and C should be deleted (i.e. the whole range A:D) otherwise the data will be 'corrupted'.

Comment: lo that was stupid.  I converted a sub from a previous answer over and left several variables.  Thanks guys for giving me a chance to salvage my dignity!

Comment: You would think so but the OP says "Column A will stay untouched..".  I was reluctant to post an answer for just that reason.  I was hoping that my answer would generate some feedback from the OP.